# How to create gun server on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, gun

I'm reading about gun db. I want to create an electron app that will sync data between two or more clients and I'm thinking to use heroku to run a gun server. I found this example code of how to setup a gun server using node and express:

```
var port    = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || process.env.PORT || process.argv[2] || 8765;
var express = require('express');
var Gun     = require('..');
require('../axe');

var app    = express();
app.use(Gun.serve);
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

var server = app.listen(port);
var gun = Gun({ file: 'data', web: server });

global.Gun = Gun; /// make global to `node --inspect` - debug only
global.gun = gun; /// make global to `node --inspect` - debug only

console.log('Server started on port ' + port + ' with /gun');
```

I don't know if this will work on heroku, as I know, heroku has it's own port to listen to. Also I found an heroku button to quickly deploy a gun server on heroku. If I use it how I can modify the code pushed on heroku if needed? Anyone has experience with this decentralized database?

Answer (score 1):

1. Heroku listens to its own port which you need to bind to. It is already done in the code you provided `process.env.PORT`.

```
var port    = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || process.env.PORT || process.argv[2] || 8765;
```

It binds to port 8765 if the environment variables `OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT`, `VCAP_APP_PORT` and `PORT` doesn't exist and there wasn't an argument provided when executing the program.

2. Heroku's file system are ephemeral. Anything that is not versioned/committed in git is lost. So using Heroku's filesystem as a database is a bad idea.

https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

You need a real database server.

3. Provide the Heroku Deploy Button link

You should be able to just fork the project on GitHub, make your changes there. Heroku Deploy Buttons are reusable.

Comment: this is the link to the heroku button: https://elements.heroku.com/buttons/amark/gun 
I've deployed it, but if I try to clone the deployed app on my local machine a get an empty repo. The strange thing is that the app is running online.

Comment: For the filesystem, I don't want to save anything on heroku, I want only to have a server that I can use to exchange data between the users of my electron app. I want to use the websockets but I rely on gun because it's a database and can fit all my needings by saving the data inside the electron app and sync if there are changes

Comment: 1. You have to fork the GitHub project, then clone from it and make your changes there. https://github.com/amark/gun 2. Data has to be saved somehow and Heroku apps are restarted once a day at which point all your data is lost. If you read the ReadMe it also says that the data is lost unless you pay for a storage server.

Comment: I don't want to store the data on the server, I just need gun to share data between the clients electron app, but as I understand it's necessary to save data on server?

Comment: Wow @TinNguyen you are fast! Such a pro. Awesome answer. Gugglo, you can use heroku as a "discovery" peer only, correct (no need for storage). But storage is cheap, so why not it up in case your Electron app dies? That is what Tin is encouraging.